# Commerce Order Total Tax line via EntityMetadataWrapper

Tags: commerce

I need the final tax amount for an order found on the commerce order total. when using dpm and entity metadata wrapper i can't seem to break it out in order to grab the value.

```
$order = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', 3);
dpm($order->commerce_order_total->getPropertyInfo());
```

Answer (score 1):

the most thorough insight on getting access to the tax line and individual subtotals. found via: https://gist.github.com/BBGuy/3e1f624eaee2088d8eee

```
// order total object
$order_total_obj = $order_wrapper->commerce_order_total->value();
// Order total (cents).
$order_total = $order_total_obj['amount'];
// order currency code
$currency_code = $order_wrapper->commerce_order_total->currency_code->value();
// subtotal without vat
$total_ex_vat = commerce_price_component_total($order_total , 'base_price');
// total tax (in this case vat 20%)
$total_vat = commerce_price_component_total($order_total , 'tax|vat_20');
// subtotal with vat
$sub_total = $total_ex_vat['amount'] + $total_vat['amount'];
// formatted price string with currency sign
$sub_total = commerce_currency_format($sub_total, $currency_code);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the final tax amount for an order from the commerce_order_total field, you can use the following code:

```
$order = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', 3);
$order_total = $order->commerce_order_total->value();
$tax_amount = $order_total['tax_amount'];
```

The commerce_order_total field is an entity_reference_revisions field, which means that it stores a reference to a revision of a tax total entity. The tax total entity stores the total tax amount in the tax_amount field.

You can also use the commerce_price Twig filter to format the tax amount as a price:

```
{# Format the tax amount as a price #}
{{ tax_amount|commerce_price }}
```